# Relationship between Beilinson’s resolution of the diagonal and functional analysis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, derived-categories

I have been wondering for long enough to embarrass myself on here by asking: is there a reason why Beilinson’s resolution of the diagonal “Coherent Sheaves on Pn and Some Problems of Linear Algebra” was originally published in a functional analysis journal? I understand it as a result in algebraic geometry, or derived categories.

If there is a reason that Beilinson’s resolution is related to functional analysis, is it fair to say that the relationship comes from the geometric Langlands correspondence? Or if there is no relationship between the two, is it fair to say that the journal title in Russian covers a broader area than the term “functional analysis” in English?

Comment: "functional analysis" in the name of the journal should be understood as "a part of mathematics that I.M. Gelfand and his seminar was interested in". So no *direct* connection was meant. There were plenty of purely algebraic or topological papers published in 'Funct. Anal. Appl'. Thus it incorporated a huge chunk of mathematics at the time. Not all of it, though,  to the best of my knowledge it never published works in logic, even its parts most relevant to the core math.